# Django admin change form/update model form Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint with SQL Server backend

Tags: sql-server, django, django-forms, django-admin

When I try to edit and update the form in Django admin, I am getting
IntegrityError at

> /admin/core/courses/144103/change/
> ('23000', "[23000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Courses'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Courses'. The duplicate key value is (144103). (2627) (SQLExecDirectW); [23000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)")

The admin model form has 2 inlines in it. Not able to understand why the issue is arising. I am not overriding any default behavior.

Comment: If you're trying to **update** a record but the error says `Cannot **insert** duplicate key` there's some disagreement in the Django code. Why would the code be trying to insert a record? Are you trying to edit/update a dbo.Courses record? If you're trying to edit/update another type of record then does that table have one or more triggers on it (that could be trying to insert other records into dbo.Courses)?

Comment: When I add a new course and update it first time; it is working fine.. But if I try updating it later, it throws the error. I am working with a legacy database and there is an update trigger there. I doubt that the update trigger is causing this error..